Seleccionar en cada set el servidor que corresponde en un partido de tenis de mesa


let timerInterval;
let timeLeft = 60;
let pointsPlayer1 = 0;
let pointsPlayer2 = 0;
let setsPlayer1 = 0;
let setsPlayer2 = 0;
let totalPoints = 0; // Nuevo contador de puntos
let firstServer; // Variable para guardar quién fue el primer servidor

function updateTimer() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
    const seconds = timeLeft % 60;
    document.getElementById('timer').textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        document.getElementById('timer').textContent = 'Warm-up Complete';
    } else {
        timeLeft--;
    }
}

document.getElementById('startWarmUp').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const confirmPositionsModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('confirmPositionsModal'));
    confirmPositionsModal.show();
});

document.getElementById('confirmPositions').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const warmUpModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('warmUpModal'));
    warmUpModal.show();
    timerInterval = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    const confirmPositionsModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('confirmPositionsModal'));
    confirmPositionsModal.hide();
});

document.getElementById('startMatchButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    const warmUpModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('warmUpModal'));
    warmUpModal.hide();

    document.getElementById('startWarmUp').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('nextGame').style.display = 'block';

    document.querySelector('.score-table').style.display = 'block';

    // Guardar el primer servidor (jugador 1)
    firstServer = 'player1'; // Suponiendo que el Player 1 es el primer servidor en el primer set
});

function toggleStartOfPlayModal() {
    const startOfPlayModal = document.getElementById('startOfPlayModal');
    const isVisible = startOfPlayModal.style.display === 'flex';

    // Toggle modal visibility
    startOfPlayModal.style.display = isVisible ? 'none' : 'flex';
}

document.getElementById('swapSides').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const player1Info = document.getElementById('player1-info');
    const player2Info = document.getElementById('player2-info');
    const player1Flag = document.getElementById('player1-flag');
    const player2Flag = document.getElementById('player2-flag');

    const tempInfo = player1Info.innerHTML;
    const tempFlagSrc = player1Flag.src;

    player1Info.innerHTML = player2Info.innerHTML;
    player1Flag.src = player2Flag.src;

    player2Info.innerHTML = tempInfo;
    player2Flag.src = tempFlagSrc;
});

function checkWinCondition() {
    if (pointsPlayer1 >= 11 || pointsPlayer2 >= 11) {
        if (pointsPlayer1 > pointsPlayer2) {
            setsPlayer1++;
        } else {
            setsPlayer2++;
        }

        // Update scoreboard
        document.getElementById('setsPlayer1').textContent = setsPlayer1;
        document.getElementById('setsPlayer2').textContent = setsPlayer2;

        // Show Next Game button
        document.getElementById('nextGame').style.display = 'block';

        // Reset points for the next game
        pointsPlayer1 = 0;
        pointsPlayer2 = 0;

        // Update displayed points
        document.getElementById('pointsPlayer1').textContent = pointsPlayer1;
        document.getElementById('pointsPlayer2').textContent = pointsPlayer2;

        // Disable point buttons until modal is closed
        disablePointButtons(true);

        // Show modal for players to confirm the score
        toggleStartOfPlayModal();
    }
}

function disablePointButtons(disable) {
    const buttons = [
        document.getElementById('addPointPlayer1'),
        document.getElementById('removePointPlayer1'),
        document.getElementById('addPointPlayer2'),
        document.getElementById('removePointPlayer2')
    ];

    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.disabled = disable; // Deshabilitar o habilitar los botones
    });
}

function checkServerChange() {
    if (totalPoints % 2 === 0) {
        toggleRoles(); // Cambiar roles de servidor y receptor
    }
}

function swapPlayerPositions() {
    const player1Card = document.querySelector('.player-card-top');
    const player2Card = document.querySelector('.player-card-bottom');

    // Cambiar la clase top con bottom para intercambiar posiciones
    player1Card.classList.toggle('player-card-top');
    player1Card.classList.toggle('player-card-bottom');

    player2Card.classList.toggle('player-card-top');
    player2Card.classList.toggle('player-card-bottom');
}

document.getElementById('addPointPlayer1').addEventListener('click', function () {
    pointsPlayer1++;
    totalPoints++; // Incrementar total de puntos
    document.getElementById('pointsPlayer1').textContent = pointsPlayer1;

    checkServerChange(); // Verificar si se debe cambiar de servidor
    checkWinCondition(); // Comprobar condición de victoria

    toggleStartOfPlayModal();
    disablePointButtons(true); // Deshabilitar botones al mostrar el modal
});

document.getElementById('removePointPlayer1').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (pointsPlayer1 > 0) pointsPlayer1--;
    document.getElementById('pointsPlayer1').textContent = pointsPlayer1;
});

document.getElementById('addPointPlayer2').addEventListener('click', function () {
    pointsPlayer2++;
    totalPoints++; // Incrementar total de puntos
    document.getElementById('pointsPlayer2').textContent = pointsPlayer2;

    checkServerChange(); // Verificar si se debe cambiar de servidor
    checkWinCondition(); // Comprobar condición de victoria

    toggleStartOfPlayModal();
    disablePointButtons(true); // Deshabilitar botones al mostrar el modal
});

document.getElementById('removePointPlayer2').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (pointsPlayer2 > 0) pointsPlayer2--;
    document.getElementById('pointsPlayer2').textContent = pointsPlayer2;
});

function toggleRoles() {
    const receiverLabel = document.getElementById('receiverLabel');
    const serverLabel = document.getElementById('serverLabel');
    const receiverCircle = document.getElementById('receiverCircle');
    const serverCircle = document.getElementById('serverCircle');

    if (receiverLabel.innerHTML === "Receiver") {
        receiverLabel.innerHTML = "Server";
        serverLabel.innerHTML = "Receiver";
        receiverCircle.innerHTML = "S";
        serverCircle.innerHTML = "R";
        document.getElementById('receiverDiv').style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementById('serverDiv').style.opacity = 0.5;
    } else {
        receiverLabel.innerHTML = "Receiver";
        serverLabel.innerHTML = "Server";
        receiverCircle.innerHTML = "R";
        serverCircle.innerHTML = "S";
        document.getElementById('receiverDiv').style.opacity = 0.5;
        document.getElementById('serverDiv').style.opacity = 1;
    }
}

document.getElementById('receiverDiv').addEventListener('click', toggleRoles);
document.getElementById('serverDiv').addEventListener('click', toggleRoles);

// Cerrar el modal "Start of Play" al hacer clic
document.getElementById('startOfPlayModal').addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    // Habilitar los botones al cerrar el modal
    disablePointButtons(false); // Habilitar todos los botones
});

// Acción para el botón Next Game
document.getElementById('nextGame').addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Reiniciar puntos
    pointsPlayer1 = 0;
    pointsPlayer2 = 0;
    document.getElementById('pointsPlayer1').textContent = pointsPlayer1;
    document.getElementById('pointsPlayer2').textContent = pointsPlayer2;

    // Ocultar botón Next Game
    this.style.display = 'none';

    // Deshabilitar los botones de puntos
    disablePointButtons(true); // Deshabilitar todos los botones

    // Cambiar posiciones de los jugadores antes de comenzar el próximo juego
    swapPlayerPositions();

    // Cambiar el servidor para el siguiente set
    toggleServer(); // Cambiar el rol del servidor al siguiente jugador

    // Mostrar el modal "Start of Play"
    toggleStartOfPlayModal(); 
});

function toggleServer() {
    // Cambiar el servidor para el siguiente set.
    const currentServer = document.getElementById('serverLabel').innerText;

    if (currentServer === "Server" && firstServer === 'player1') {
        // Si el primer servidor fue el jugador 1 y actualmente es el "Server", el siguiente debe ser el jugador 2.
        firstServer = 'player2'; // Cambiamos el servidor inicial al segundo jugador
        toggleRoles(); // Cambiar roles visualmente
    } else if (currentServer === "Server" && firstServer === 'player2') {
        // Si el primer servidor fue el jugador 2 y actualmente es el "Server", el siguiente debe ser el jugador 1.
        firstServer = 'player1'; // Cambiamos el servidor inicial al primer jugador
        toggleRoles(); // Cambiar roles visualmente
    }
    // Configuración inicial: siempre iniciar el primer set con el jugador 1 como servidor
    if (setsPlayer1 === 0 && setsPlayer2 === 0) {
        firstServer = 'player1'; // Asegurarnos de que comience el jugador 1
    }
}
body {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.table-container {
    background-color: #006400;
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#startOfPlayModal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: orange;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.divider-vertical,
.divider-horizontal {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.divider-vertical {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 5px;
}

.divider-horizontal {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 5px;
}

.player-card {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}

.player-info {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.circle-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.server-container,
.receiver-container {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.receiver-container {
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: -140px;
}

.server-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: -140px;
}

.player-card-top {
    top: 10%;
    right: 0;
}

.player-card-bottom {
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 0;
}

.action-buttons {
    background-color: #dedede;
    padding: 15px;
}

.action-buttons .btn {
    width: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.timer-circle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.score-table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ping Pong Match</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> <!-- Vincular el archivo CSS -->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center vh-100">
        <div class="table-container">
            <div class="divider-vertical"></div>
            <div class="divider-horizontal"></div>

            <div class="receiver-container" id="receiverDiv">
                <div class="circle-icon" id="receiverCircle">R</div>
                <div class="label-text" id="receiverLabel">Receiver</div>
            </div>

            <div class="server-container" id="serverDiv">
                <div class="circle-icon" id="serverCircle">S</div>
                <div class="label-text" id="serverLabel">Server</div>
            </div>

            <div class="player-card player-card-top">
                <img src="assets/fra.png" alt="Bandera Francia" class="rounded-circle" width="40" height="40" id="player1-flag">
                <div class="player-info" id="player1-info">
                    <strong>Player 1</strong><br>
                    LEBRUN Felix<br>
                    FRA
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="player-card player-card-bottom">
                <img src="assets/eng.png" alt="Bandera Inglaterra" class="rounded-circle" width="40" height="40" id="player2-flag">
                <div class="player-info" id="player2-info">
                    <strong>Player 2</strong><br>
                    SOSA Marcelo<br>
                    PAR
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="startOfPlayModal">
                Start of Play
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="action-buttons d-flex justify-content-evenly w-100">
            <button id="swapSides" type="button" class="btn btn-teal btn-lg" style="background-color: #20b2aa; color: #ffffff;">Swap Sides</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="background-color: #ff8c00; color: #ffffff;" id="startWarmUp">Start Warm Up</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="nextGame" style="display: none;">Next Game</button>
        </div>

        <div class="score-table text-center">
            <table class="table table-dark table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="setsPlayer1">0</td>
                        <td id="setsPlayer2">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="pointsPlayer1">0</td>
                        <td id="pointsPlayer2">0</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly mt-3">
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="addPointPlayer1">Add Point P1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" id="removePointPlayer1">Remove Point P1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="addPointPlayer2">Add Point P2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" id="removePointPlayer2">Remove Point P2</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="warmUpModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Warm-up Timer</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="timer-circle" id="timer">1:00</div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="startMatchButton">Start Match</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="confirmPositionsModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="confirmPositionsLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmPositionsLabel">Confirm Player Positions</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p style="color: orange;">Note: Can't set players positions after warmup. Please set players positions before warmup.</p>
                    <p>Is Players Positions Set?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="confirmPositions">Confirm</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Vincular el archivo JS -->
</body>

</html>



Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para tenis de mesa y me he quedado atascado con la lógica de alternancia de servicio entre jugadores.
La lógica que quiero implementar es la siguiente:

Inicio de Set: Al iniciar cada set, debo asignar el servidor (por ejemplo, Player 1) y marcar quién realiza el servicio.
Cambio de Servidor al Terminar el Set: Al terminar el set actual y hacer clic en el botón para iniciar el siguiente set, el servidor debe cambiar automáticamente al otro jugador (es decir, si Player 1 fue el servidor en el primer set, el servidor en el siguiente set debe ser Player 2).
Alternancia Cada Dos Puntos: Durante el set, el servicio debe alternarse cada dos puntos acumulados, sin importar quién anote. Esto significa que después de dos puntos, el servidor cambia al siguiente jugador automáticamente.

Esta es la lógica de cambio de servidor que estoy intentando lograr, pero no estoy seguro de cómo implementarla. ¿Podrías ayudarme a resolverla?

Digamos que parte sacando el player_1, la secuencia es la siguiente

La columna "Bloque" es una agrupación de cada ronda de saques
Para obtener el número de bloque a partir del total de puntos, solo debes dividir por 2 y redondear para abajo
let bloque = Math.floor((pointsPlayer1 + pointsPlayer2) / 2);

Luego, si observas bien, te darás cuenta de que cada vez que el bloque es par el saque pertenece al que comenzó sacando, y si es impar saca el otro jugador. Entonces, podrías crear una función que te diga quien saca:
const getServicio = (puntos) =>
   Math.floor(puntos / 2) % 2 == 0 ? firstServer : 
   (firstServer == "player1"? "player2" : "player1" );

Una pequeña demo para comprobación:


let pointsPlayer1 = 0;
let pointsPlayer2 = 0;
let firstServer = "player1";

const getServicio = (puntos) =>
   Math.floor(puntos / 2) % 2 == 0 ? firstServer : 
   (firstServer == "player1"? "player2" : "player1" );
   
document.querySelectorAll("input:not([read-only])").forEach(i=> i.addEventListener("input",puntosTrigger));

function puntosTrigger(){
  pointsPlayer1 = p1.valueAsNumber;
  pointsPlayer2 = p2.valueAsNumber;
  total.value = pointsPlayer1 + pointsPlayer2;
  saca.value = getServicio(pointsPlayer1 + pointsPlayer2);
}
<table><tr><td>Player 1</td><td><input id="p1" type="number" value="0" min="0"></td></tr><tr><td>Player 2</td><td><input id="p2" type="number" value="0" min="0"></td></tr><tr><td>Total</td><td><input id="total" type="number" readonly></td></tr><tr><td>Saca</td><td><input id="saca" type="text" readonly></td></tr></table>




Por último, te recomiendo que uses clases. Generalmente los juegos se acomodan muy bien con la POO
